# Best use of the arguments property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What's the right way to use the arguments property of a function?
This is how I'm currently using it, but I'm pretty sure I'm not using it correctly:

First, I define my parameters:

```
parameters = {};
parameters.ID = $tr.data('ID');
parameters.Name = 'Name goes here';
parameters.td = $td;
UpdateName(parameters);
```

And in the function:

```
var UpdateName = function(){
    var local = {};
    local.ID = arguments[0].ID;
    local.Name = arguments[0].Name;
    local.td = arguments[0].td;

    local.jqXHR = $.ajax('Remote/Ajax.cfc', {
        data: {
            method:'UpdateName'
            ,returnformat:'json'
            ,ID:local.ID
            ,Name:local.Name
        }
    });
    local.jqXHR.success(function(result){
        if (result.MSG == '') {
            local.td.text(local.Name).addClass('success');
        } else {
            local.td.addClass('err');
        };
    });
    local.jqXHR.error(function(result){
        local.td.addClass('err');
    });
}
```

Comment: If the ajax call finished extremely quickly, the success and error functions might not be defined. Better to define those as part of the settings object passed to `$.ajax`.

Comment: what reason do you have for calling a function in this way?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the syntax of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript [functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html) are capable of using named arguments.

In your case, this could simplify your code as follows:

```
var UpdateName = function(local) {
    $.ajax('Remote/Ajax.cfc', {
        data: {
            method:'UpdateName',
            returnformat:'json',
            ID:local.ID,
            Name:local.Name,
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.MSG == '') {
                    local.td.text(local.Name).addClass('success');
                } else {
                    local.td.addClass('err');
                }
            },
            error: function(result) {
                local.td.addClass('err');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I modified the code so that you don't need to keep a reference to jqXHR anymore since you aren't doing anything with it anyway. I also moved the leading commas to the end of each line, but that is just a preference.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code.  I got into the habit of putting the commas first due to SQL Server doing that, but I will change my habits from now on when it comes to js code.

Comment: Really, what I would like to use is function(arguments) instead of functon(local), because that's similar to the other language that I'm used to, but the word 'arguments' is a keyword that I can't use.

Comment: You could technically use `function(arguments)` if you really wanted to, but I wouldn't recommend it. Although it has a special purpose, `arguments` doesn't appear to be a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) so you are allowed to redefine it as you see fit. See [http://jsfiddle.net/yxWZS/](http://jsfiddle.net/yxWZS/) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

The `arguments` object is most useful for functions that accept an arbitrary/unknown number of arguments. The MDC gives [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for creating HTML lists of any length:

```
function list(type) {
  var result = "<" + type + "l>";

  // iterate through non-type arguments
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
    result += "<li>" + arguments[i] + "</li>";

  result += "</" + type + "l>"; // end list

  return result;
}
```

...which can be used like this:

```
var listHTML = list("u", "One", "Two", "Three");
// listHTML is "<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>"
```

Because of `arguments`, we can pass any number of items to `list` and it just works. (Notice that even in this case the known parameter, `type`, is named and iteration of `arguments` begins on its second element.)

Your list of parameters is well-defined, so there's no reason not to simply name the parameters in your function declaration. Using `arguments` as you are is unnecessary and harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

You technically are using it correctly, but I don't see the practical point in your code though. The `arguments` variable contains a array-like object of the arguments passed to a function. E.g.

```
function test() {
    alert(arguments[0]);
    alert(arguments[1]);
}
test("Hello", 123); // alerts Hello and 123
```

In your example, instead of an object, you can pass the properties as arguments and retrieve them from `arguments`.